# Java -jar No Sound Error with cgoban.jar

Tags: java, audio, jar, javasound

### Situation

The problem I have encountered is that there will be no sound output from running my *.jar file. I will start it with `java -jar cgoban.jar` and it works fine except there is no sound.

### Possible Solutions

There is a workaround for this problem discussed here: https://senseis.xmp.net/?CgobanProblemsAndSolutions.
It says to employ the Java Web Start with

```
LIBXCB_ALLOW_SLOPPY_LOCK=true padsp javaws http://files.gokgs.com/javaBin/cgoban.jnlp
```

and use the `jlnp` file from here: http://files.gokgs.com/javaBin/cgoban.jnlp.

However, since this workaround includes downloading the `jar`-file on every start this is not an option for me (as I use an offline machine, bandwidth limitations etc.)

---

A possible solution might be to run (since it works with javaws)

```
LIBXCB_ALLOW_SLOPPY_LOCK=true padsp java -jar cgoban.jar
```

but there is still no sound. I don't understand why it works for javaws, but not for `java -jar`.

---

Unluckily it did not help to run

```
java -jar -Dsun.sound.useNewAudioEngine="false" cgoban.jar
```

But thanks for commenting.

---

Another possible solution that I attempted was to download and edit above `jlnp`-file. I don't want to download the `jar`-file every time the application starts. So maybe it is possible to download the `jar`-file once and then have the local `jlnp`-file point to the local copy (instead of the remote `jar`-file). However, as my programming skills suck, I have not been able to pull this off.

### Additional Information

I'm running an Ubuntu machine with Java installed. `java -version` gives me the following output:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

An up-to-date version of `cgoban.jar` for download is available from here:
http://files.gokgs.com/javaBin/cgoban.jar

Comment: Can you try `LIBXCB_ALLOW_SLOPPY_LOCK=true padsp java -jar cgoban.jar`? You could also try what they suggest for missing sounds (`-Dsun.sound.useNewAudioEngine="false"`)

Comment: It is very common problem that sounds which will play in an IDE will not play from a Jar. The most common reasons involve addressing the sound files. Can you give us more info: (1) error message when the io code for reading the sound file fails (some people bypass message creation in the required "catch" clauses--do not do so); (2) file locations in the jar for the sound files and the calling code; (3) string used to address the file; (4) whether you use URL or File--the File class does not work for addresses within a Jar.

Comment: *"However, since this workaround includes downloading the jar-file on every start.."* 1) No, Jars downloaded with JNLP are cached locally. Then they are only downloaded when the Jar on the server changes, but.. A) It is not really a 'workaround' to anything. As long as the Jar is on the run-time class-path of the app. it should work, and JNLP is only one way to achieve that. B) JWS (that uses the JNLP files) will be removed from the API soon, in any case. - Follow the advice of @PhilFreihofner. It's your best bet at solving this problem.

Comment: @freihofner I am not the maintainer of the `cgoban.jar` nor did I mess with the source code. I'm afraid I don't know how to give you any of the requested information at all...

Comment: Neat, I just realized this is a "Go" program. I may have even loaded it an played a few games with it on an earlier PC. Unfortunately I won't be able to help much in terms of figuring out how to make the program run with sound from the jar file. If it was written correctly, it should just work, as far as I know. My limited experience with Ubuntu Java was from several years ago (Java 6 era) and sound worked fine from jar files at that time. I'd take it up with the help offered at the source web site. I imagine you have already tried that.